# Javadoc formatting issue with multiline code

Tags: java, javadoc

I have the following Javadoc which has multiline code:

```
     * <p>Usage example:
 * <code>
 *  ConfigurationProperty property = ConfigurationProperty.Builder
 *                                      .create()
 *                                      .withHotKey("testKey")
 *                                  .withRunnableContext("testContext")
 *                                  .withRunnableContextType("APPLICATION")
 *                                  .build();
 * </code>
 * 
 * The {@link ConfigurationProperty.Builder#withRunnableContextType(String type) method 
 * throws an {@link IllegalArgumentException} if the provided type is not supported in
 * {@link ConfigurationProperty#RUNNABLE_CONTEXT_TYPE}
```

My issue is that the code is not getting displayed with right indentation in the generated Javadoc. The following is what i see in the generated Javadoc without any indentation:

```
Immutable implementation of a ConfigurationProperty. This class is  
 immutable, and so is thread safe. An instance of the ConfigurationProperty
can be obtained by using the ConfigurationProperty.Builder 

Usage example: ConfigurationProperty property =    
ConfigurationProperty.Builder .create() .withHotKey("testKey")   
.withRunnableContext("testContext") .withRunnableContextType("APPLICATION")   
.build(); } The method throws an IllegalArgumentException if the provided 
type is not supported in ConfigurationProperty.RUNNABLE_CONTEXT_TYPE
```

If I replace code by pre tags, then just the first line of code displays.
[image]
 Why is this so. How do I fix this?
Any thoughts on how to correct this?

Please advise,

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `<pre>` instead of `<code>`.

[image]

Comment: By using <pre> most part of the code got truncated. Why is this so? I just see the following now: "ConfigurationProperty property = ConfigurationProperty.Builder 
" and the rest of the javadoc is wipedout

Comment: I just updated my answer and I must say that it works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks, I just added the same code with pre text in the original post as well, but could not see it.... any thoughts why this is showing that way? Should the java version or eclipse version matter? I am on java v1.7..Eclipse Helios.. any javadoc dependency to be checked?

Comment: I am not sure why this happens. Did you try generating HTML javadoc from console using `javadoc.exe`? Does problem stay? If not then Java version is OK and problem could be in Eclipse. Maybe consider updating your IDE, maybe as it could be some bug which could already be solved. Also if you are interested I am using Java 8 with Eclipse Luna.

Comment: You can also try installing clean version of your Eclipse to see how it generates Javadoc. If it does it correctly try adding your dependencies and see which one causes the problem.